# I want my spawned players to be able to overlap with each other(without layers)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, spawning

I have a unity-c# code that will spawn player on position(0,1,0) on start. I want them to be able to overlap on the same position.

Right now my code only spawns 1 player. but when I drag another one from my prefab they cant overlap. they just collide. I am planing to add at least 50 players and I do not want to create layers for all of them.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision info)
    {
        if(info.collider.tag != "Ground")
        {
            if(info.collider.tag == "Player")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                this.enabled = false;
                FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
                LastLocation();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public GameObject player;

    [SerializeField]
    public Transform respawnpoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(player, respawnpoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could put a layer on your player prefab, and simply uncheck this layer with himself in the collision matrix under Project settings > Physics.